# Removing unnecessary rows from a table: Error 5941 - The requested member of the collection does not exist

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

This code is removing unnecessary rows from a table:

```vb
With ActiveDocument.Tables(tblcount - a)
    For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Len(.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text) = 3 Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        ElseIf Len(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text) = 3 Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

It works on multiple documents, but doesn't on some.

It gives

> Run-time error '5941' The requested member of the collection does not exist.

When I debug it shows `ElseIf Len(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text) = 3 Then` has the error.

Comment: 'The number of tables in the entire document: 
[tblcount = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count]      [a = 6] 'This number is subtracted from the total number of tables to get table I need to cleanup @Domenic

Comment: Sounds as though the row that generates the error either has only one cell, or has merged cells.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, The table has more than one cell. Also, this code works successfully with documents with the same table. It seems the issue has to do with the document itself.

Comment: @Domenic, I confirmed tblcount-a is 53

Comment: @Domenic that's correct. I have a total of 59 tables, I need to get to the 53rd table, hence I am doing tblcnt-a (59-6)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is related to a particular file, not all files throw the error. In that case you need to run the code under the debugger and find with a problematic file which property or method exactly gives the error.

The problematic line of code look in the following way:

```
 ElseIf Len(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text) = 3 Then
```

So, I'd suggest breaking the chain of property and method calls by declaring them on separate lines of code. Following this way you will be able to locate the problematic call exactly.

Comment: No.1 the error must show the line that threw the error. Can you provide that? No.2 the for loop will fail with the exact same error is a table has vertically merged cells (ie. the table is non-uniform). No.3 to deal with non-uniform tables a more robust implementation is to loop all cells using the .next property while it is non-empty. The check on column van be done using property .columnIndex

Comment: A single line of code pointed by the error contains multiple property and method calls. It is not clear which one is throwing an exception.

Comment: so I tested above code and when it flags an error and the on the error window click on DEBUG it does bring up the offending line of code. Anyway, there are 2 lines of code that can throw the reported error: 1) the refence to ActiveDocuments.Tables(tblCount -a) if a >= tblCount and 2) any reference to .Cell in case the table has merged cells.